# Prime to $p$ monodromy of local system on rigid variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-representations, rigid-analytic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

Suppose $F$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, and $X$ is a rigid variety over $F$. I saw in proposition 3.7 of [Oswal, Shankar, Zhu, and Patel - A $p$-adic analogue of Borel's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.06104): "Let $\mathbb L$ be a local system on $X$ with prime to $p$ monodromy".

What is the definition of "prime to $p$" monodromy?

I guess this is the definition: Let $\pi_1$ be the étale fundamental group of $X$, and let $$\pi_1'=\varprojlim_{\substack{\text{open normal $H$ such that} \\ \text{$\pi_1/H$ has prime to $p$ order}}}\pi_1/H,$$
and we say $\mathbb L$ has prime to $p$ monodromy if the action of $\pi_1$ on geometric fibers of $\mathbb L$ induces an action of $\pi_1'$ (since $\pi_1'$ is a quotient of $\pi_1$).

But I don't know whether this definition is true.

Comment: What was the paper?

Comment: What does it mean for a definition to be untrue? Your definition is also what I would guess if I saw that statement (with no further helpful context).